# How to solve S-IX deadlock without using the Snapshot isolation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Ok, I got an weird problem: I got two server-side api, one is to select data from A table; the Other one is to Insert new record to B table with part of the data and PK from first one. They should not have any problem to each other with the Usual actions.

Somehow, I detected someone which called my select and insert function at less than 0.005 sec on my SQL monitor, which caused S-IX deadlock. So I searched the Internet and found an solution that told me to enable the Snapshot isolation. But I tried it on my test DB(which its total size is about 223MB), that Alter Database command does not show any sight of finishing after 1 hour execution, so this is intolerable to execute it on the Production DB with such long Downtime(Which its data size is bigger than the Test one).

So my question is: Does anyone know the Other way to solve the S-IX deadlock?(Without lower the Throughput.)

P.S.: My DB is SQL Server 2008

Comment: maybe a little please?

Comment: @krtek Do you mean the Throughput? Since that DB is one of our company's money earning way, and the Boss is trying to make more people to use our service. I'll get snapped if I do so.